# How to use a DevExpress Find bar to search but not filter a Grid View table?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a Grid Control that contains a large amount of hexadecimal data and I want to be able to search for a particular address in the table using the provided Find search bar. However, I do not want it to filter out all the data as seen in the **top image**. Instead, I would like to just scroll down to the value and not do any filtering **(bottom image)**. I've been playing with some of the OptionsFind properties under the Grid Viewer object, but none of them seem to apply to my current situation. Is there a way to do this with the DevExpress find bar, or do I need to use a different control? If so, how can this be accomplished? Thanks! Please comment for more information and I will edit the question.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this problem was as follows.

- Disable the Find, Clear, and Close buttons from OptionsFind
- Create the following CustomRowFilter event handler for the GridView object. (This prevents the table from being filtered by setting the handled property to true every time a filter is attempted.)
- Create a custom Search button which changes the currently focused row after locating which row the data contained in the FindFilterText is in.

  ```
  private void gridViewDataViewer_CustomRowFilter(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowFilterEventArgs e)
  {
      e.Handled = true;
      e.Visible = true;  
  }


  private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int rowHandle = gridViewDataViewer.LocateByValue("Column Name", gridViewDataViewer.FindFilterText);
      gridViewDataViewer.FocusedRowHandle = gridViewDataViewer.GetVisibleRowHandle(rowHandle);

  }
  ```

Comment: Good job! I try to find a solution for 2 hours, and in the end I left with an almost similar solution has your solution.

Comment: @AbdellahOUMGHAR Wow! I appreciate you spending all that time trying to help me out! Thanks friend!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, Thank you too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CustomRowFilter` to prevents grid from filtre, and use `ColumnFilterChanged` for focused the row that contains a searched value:

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowFilter(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowFilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    e.Visible = true;

}

private void gridView1_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
    {
        object b = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Address");
        if (b != null && b.ToString().Contains(gridView1.FindFilterText))
        {
            gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = i;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```